# How can I change month name in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I want to make my database language Turkish. I want to take month name Turkish but its English.

I tried [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/locale-support.html), but It doesn't work for me. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: You don't need to store turkish language data in database. Rather, have it in English in your database, retrieve the necessary data and perform the localization/globalization conversion in your application end while displaying the data to your end user.

Again, going by the documentation you need to set the [`lc_time_names`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lc_time_names) global variable to `tr-TR` to have turkish language effict

Comment: I couldn't find how i can do this.

Comment: I try tr-TR It is run. After that I run SELECT @@lc_time_names; but its still en_US.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `momentjs` which is a javascript language for date and time handling. It comes with another package called `moment.locale` to format your dates in other languages:

```
moment.locale("tr-TR").format('LLL');
```

Per @Nashenas:

With momentjs 2.8+, do the following:

```
moment.locale("tr-TR").format('LLL');
```

For current version of momentjs (2016)

```
moment.locale("tr-TR");
```

just returns "de" and no moment-object.

To get a formated date you need:

```
moment().locale("tr-TR").format('LLL');
```

More info [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/instance-locale/).

Create a plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/ffT9JxQcVuQaHKGzYQZS?p=preview

Comment: Nothing happen again.. Still it is english